# Accessing table data from two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

New to rails and having some issues with accessing data from a separate table.

```
class Trial < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :site_id

  has_many :sites

end


class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :site_id, :site_name

  belongs_to :trial

end
```

My view.

```
<table class="table">
    <% @list.each do |list| %>
    <tr>
    <td>
  <%= link_to list.site_name, view_path %>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

I want to be able to list for each record the site_name where Trial and Site id's match but not sure of the best approach to take.

Comment: @list = Site.where('site_id = ?', trail.site_id)

Comment: Trails do not have `site_id`, at least according to how you've defined the model associations. Maybe you meant that a trail belongs to a site and that a site has many trails? In that case then, you could define `@list` as just `site.trails`